# Rolling ball while winding a tape

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

I've been trying to solve this for a hours but i can't build the equations related problem involving this question, could someone help me?

a ball of mass $m$ and radius $r$ rolls down without sliding along an inclined plane of $\alpha$ slope and height $h$, while winding on a thin tape of density $\rho$ (Assume that due to the bearing link the coiled length is equal to
distance traveled by the center of mass).

(a) Determine the maximum horizontal distance the ball reaches. (Disregard the
tape thickness).

(b) Now consider that the tape thickness is $\epsilon$, what is the new maximum position?

[image]

Comment: the problem only say that, maybe the mass gain would stop the ball? I really don't know... thick as tape thickness (i forgot to put the value) sorry!

Comment: OK, that makes sense now.